# Why am I not getting the result of the addition?

Tags: scripts

I have written the following script file from my book.

```
a=2
b=3 
c=$[a+b]
echo 'The result is:' $c
```

After executing this program, instead of getting 5, I am getting output as:

```
The result is: $[a+b]
```

Comment: It should work in bash. Try putting `#!/bin/bash` at the start of your script.

Comment: @Jos try it :) I thought so too... It is now depreciated, and so i guess that is why it wouldn't work... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348902/how-can-i-add-numbers-in-a-bash-script

Comment: Works for me, @Tim. Yes I tried it first.

Comment: @Jos Event after adding the quoted string at the start, the output remained the same.

Comment: @Jos, oh so it does, miss type... OP: Are you doing this in a bash script or a terminal?

Comment: @tim, terminal. However `echo $0` returns bash.

Comment: Am I the only one who simply gets 5?

Comment: @Jacob nope, it is working for all of us too... It's strange. My answer below worked for OP, when this one ^^ didn't

Comment: @Tim Ah, I should read more careful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `[]`:

Go for this (with the `(())` brackets:

```
a=2
b=3
c=$((a+b))
echo 'The result is:' $c
```

returns:

```
The result is: 5
```

Comment: This is working.